# How to add a custom field in customized checkout step?

Tags: magento2, checkout-page, datepicker

I have referred the below link for adding a custom field in the checkout

http://vagento.com/magento-2-add-custom-field-checkout-address-form/

It's working fine. How to do the same in a customized checkout step?.

Please reply with your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the $jsLayout array for custom step XML configuration

See below the **bold** array filed of **$jsLayout** array. Change the bold one as per your custom step XML Configuration.

$jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['**shipping-step**']['children']
        ['**shippingAddress**']['children']['**shipping-address-fieldset**']['children']['**custom_field**'] =

Comment: Thanks. In my case, we have two customized options in the checkout. One is School and another one is Private person. Customer can checkout via School as well as Private person. Now, I want to add a custom field in the step Shipping address at School option.